# Built-in data validation function for URLs

Tags: forms, front-end

I have a front-end form where people can submit their website URL.

I'm actually verifying URLs in Wordpress with a PHP function and I would like to know if there is a built-in function that allows me to do this ?

This is the function that I am actually using :

```
function validateURL($URL) {
    $v = "/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?\/?/i";
    return (bool)preg_match($v, $URL);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `esc_url( $url )` for URLs that should be displayed and `esc_url_raw( $url )` if the URL should be sent to the database.

- The first will replace bare ampersands `&` with `&#038;`.
- The second is a wrapper for the first; it will just suppress the escaping of ampersands.
- Both functions will check the protocol. See `wp_allowed_protocols()` for the list:
  `'http', 'https', 'ftp', 'ftps', 'mailto', 'news', 'irc', 'gopher', 'nntp', 'feed', 'telnet', 'mms', 'rtsp', 'svn', 'tel', 'fax', 'xmpp'`
  So an URL like `javascript:alert("Hacked!");` will not get through.

These functions are not exactly *validators*. They *sanitize* the value. But you should use them whenever you have an URL to save or to display.

There is also `wp_validate_redirect( $location, $default )`.

`$location` is an URL here and `$default` a fallback URL if the first value doesn't validate. From its doc block:

> Validates a URL for use in a redirect.
>
> Checks whether the $location is using an allowed host, if it has an absolute
> path. A plugin can therefore set or remove allowed host(s) to or from the list.

Note the allowed hosts do not include all (sub) domains of a multi-site installation. No idea why.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a function that validates a URL, just one that sanitizes a string for use within a URL ([`sanitize_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/sanitize_title)).

There's a [PHP filter](http://php.net/manual/en/book.filter.php) that will validate URLs: [`FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php).